Is it safe to set the statistics target to zero for numeric columns?
I have some PostgreSQL tables with columns of type:
timestamp without time zone
interval
text
numeric
For example assume a table like:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_foo(
    "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    granularity interval NOT NULL,
    dimension_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    dimension_2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table_foo_pk PRIMARY KEY ("timestamp", granularity, dimension_1, dimension_2),
    data_volume_down NUMERIC NOT NULL default 0,
    data_volume_up NUMERIC NOT NULL default 0
)

and the type of queries that want to perform is the following:
Select
    timestamp,
    granularity,
    dimension_1,
    dimension_2,
    SUM(data_volume_down+data_volume_up) as total_volume
From table_foo
WHERE timestamp > '2024-09-30 00:00'
    AND granularity = '1 day'
GROUP BY timestamp, granularity, dimension_1, dimension_2
ORDER BY total_volume
LIMIT 10;

I read in the manual the following:

It might be useful to do that for columns that are never used as part of the WHERE, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clauses of queries, since the planner will have no use for statistics on such columns.

Is it safe to set statistics equal to 0 for numeric columns when a value that is computed from them is used in "order by" clause?

Very probably you try to solve some problem, so you shuld briefly mention it as well. Column without statistics will potentialy behave suboptimal for some queries. Do you know all your queries?

The analyze command takes a lot of time, so I am trying to fine tune analyzer for this particular table. There are no other queries having the numeric columns in "order by" clause nor in "group by" nor in "where". And in most cases the formula is not a simple sum but could be more complex, like: (a + b) *c / d

ANALYZE will still do its work, it's still collecting stats for your table. That some columns from the collected records are ignored, so be it. You might save half a microsecond or so.

If that's the only statement that uses the columns data_volume_down and data_volume_up, you might as well disable statistics for these columns.
However, that will only speed up ANALYZE and will probably not affect the performance of the query. It is probably a micro-optimization that is not worth the effort.
You would probably see a bigger performance gain if you define these columns as double precision rather than numeric.

In the actual table that I have the numeric columns are more than 2. So, I have 15 numeric columns and 4 other columns. I have compared the analyze command before and after disable stats for the numeric columns and the improvement is big: more than 100%.
May you elaborate  about the gain from changing the column type to double precision? Is this going to affect the queries and how? Would it also make analyze command faster?

It would not speed up ANALYZE, but the calculation in your query. Normally, people don't try to optimize ANALYZE, because that is run in the background by autovacuum. But I admit that reducing the load from autovacuum is valuable.

It's not the daemon that takes much time, but the manual vacuum analyze that I run once per day. Btw, the table is partitioned so, based on docs I have to analyze the parent table in order to update the inheritance tree

That is true. Point taken.
